# Add HTML form fields from JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Apps Script, I have created an HTML page with a form that uses its inputs to populate a Google sheet. This all works fine but I would like to now use a different form that (depending on the data present) will dynamically create the fields that are in the form. My code so far:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent form from submitting
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function FormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(FormSuccess).EnterData(formObject);

      }
      function FormSuccess() {
        var resets = document.getElementsByClassName("reset");
        for (var i = 0; i < resets.length; i++) {
          resets[i].value = "";
        }

        google.script.run.ProgramSuccess();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="entryForm" onsubmit="FormSubmit(this)">
      Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <br>
      Client Name:<br>
      <input class = "reset" type="text" name="clientName">
      <br>
      Task:<br>
      <input class = "reset" type="text" name="task">
      <br>
      Hours:<br>
      <input class = "reset" type="number" name="hours" min="0" step="0.01">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <input type="reset">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function EnterData(fObject) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.activate();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
  var entries = [[timestamp, fObject.name, fObject.clientName, fObject.projectType, fObject.task, fObject.hours]];
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 6);

  if ((lastRow % 2) == 0) {
    range.setValues(entries).setBackground("#d9d9d9");
  }
  else  {
    range.setValues(entries);
  }

  return;
}

function ProgramSuccess() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.toast("Data Entry Successful");
}
```

For example, is it possible to pass in an object to HTML containing a form tag and its options/classes and have HTML automatically create the form based off that info?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can totally design a new HTML form every time the user opens it if you want.  You could hide or show existing HTML elements.  You could add or delete HTML elements.  You could have a totally empty form tag and put all new elements inside of it every time.  You need to know the basic capabilities that are available.  For example: [Link to innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) And [Create Element Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)  And [Element Remove Child](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp)

Comment: I find it helpful to be able to use other web development tools to build the html pages and then storage in files and recover with Google Apps Script.  It helps to minimize the amount of tedious boiler plate work that you can have with html pages.